# How can I see what packages are in my external jars?

Tags: eclipse, jar, package, java

In Java project, if I go to the java build path, I can see a list of external libraries, all as jar formats.

What I'm wanting to know which packages are in these jars.

There's an apache package somewhere, I need to find it.

Comment: In eclipse, just hold down CTRL+SHIFT+T and write the class name. If you don't know the class name, you can start typing the package. Eclipse will auto-complete.

Comment: `unzip -l jarName.jar`

Comment: A jar file is a zip file.  Any zip tool will give you a listing of the contents.

Comment: Sure, unzipping is one way to do it, but that's quite a burdunsome way to do it, especially if there are a lot of external jars. I was hoping to get just a list of packages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some of class in this package

then you ctrl+click left on this class in eclipse you can go to this class.

at last,you click Link with Editor, you can find whick package it belong.